# List intersection by criteria in .NET

Tags: c#, linq, tuples, intersection, ilist

Here is my point:
here is data class:

```
class Data
{
public string name; 
public int version;
}
```

here is data lists:

```
Ilist<Data> List_old = {new Data{name = "1", version = 1}, new Data{name = "2", version = 1}};
Ilist<Data> List_new = {new Data{name = "1", version = 2}, new Data{name = "3", version = 1}, new Data{name = "2", version = 1}};
```

As result I need a list of tuples - `IList<Tuple<Data, Data>>` - first data object is from List_new, second from List_old, taken by criteria - data objects have the same name but - first have greater version that the second OR second is null if there in List_old there is no any data item with the same name from List_new.
Considering that the result should be:

```
IList<Tuple<Data, Data>> result = { {List_new[0], List_old[0]}, {List_new[1], null}};
```

could You help with the LINQ code which could perform that?
I blow my brains with this...

Comment: Also - there is any equivalent of Tuple from Framework 4.0 to be used in Framework 2.0-3.5?

Comment: You can easily find source for Tuple and create your own class library, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: You don't show List_new[2] anywhere in your results, is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've interpreted your question correctly:

```
var q = 
    (from n in List_new
    join tmp in List_old on n.name equals tmp.name into g
    from o in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where o == null || o.version < n.version
    select new Tuple<Data, Data>(n, o)).ToList();
```

Comment: Hmmm, calling the extension method directly for a left join was more of a pain than i thought.  I'll happily defer to the LINQ query expression syntax :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank You guys - but it seems that I got answer to both my questions:
LINQ code:

```
IList<Tuple<Data,Data> > UpdateList = List_new.Where(
delegate(Data item)
{
return List_old.Any(y => item.name == y.name && item.Version > y.Version) ||
!List_old.Any(y => item.name == y.name);
}
).Select(
delegate(Data item)
{
Data old_item = List_old.FirstOrDefault(y => item.name == y.name && item.Version > y.Version);
return new Tuple<Data,Data>(item, old_item);
}
).ToList();
```

for using Tuple in .NET 2.0-3.5 - look [here](http://systemtuples.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I know that this can be optimized a lot - but a it's just a start point

Comment: What was wrong with the left join solution I gave? This looks much more complicated and wont have as good performance.